# ViewPager draggable

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want to lock dragging in `ViewPager` while images are not downloaded
Here is snippet from my activity:

```
    pager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_menu);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();   
    Log.d(TAG, "ViewPager adapter created");
    mPagerAdapter  = new MyPagerAdapter(fm);
    pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
```

How do I forbid user to drag in certain circumstances?

Comment: Do you want to disable viewPager swipes?

Comment: Exactly! The idea is that user cannot swipe while images aren't yet downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to use perfect android image tool - [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Then you need to create your own class extends ViewPager thms like [this](http://blog.svpino.com/2011/08/disabling-pagingswiping-on-android.html) 
When your images are downloaded just change *enabled* value to true.
Universal image loader has some listeners that notify you about image dowloading process, you can use onLoadingComplete() method to set your pager swipeable again.

```
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrl, imageView, options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadingStarted() {
       spinner.show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoadingFailed(FailReason failReason) {
        spinner.hide();
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(Bitmap loadedImage) {
        spinner.hide();

    }
    @Override
    public void onLoadingCancelled() {
        // Do nothing
    }
```

});

Comment: I want to avoid using it due to some specifications